# Accessing ListBox within DataGrid 2nd and 3rd columns

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, listbox

I've managed to bind my data to a datagrid and listbox via ObservableCollection. I've also managed to get the listbox items from the first column of my datagrid using the below code. Can anyone tell me how to access the listboxes within the second and third columns as I'm only getting the first column containing my listboxes? (I thought my FindVisualChild merthod would have pulled ALL listboxes from the datagrid irrespective of which column they were in and I could have separated them via a change in tag name or something - I was wrong I guess...)

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Update Job Step Grid ListBox
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridJobSteps.Items.Count; i++)
    {                
        DependencyObject obj = dataGridJobSteps.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);
        ListBox _listBox = FindVisualChild<ListBox>(obj);

        var selectedItems = _listBox.Items;
        foreach (var selectedItem in selectedItems)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(selectedItem.ToString());
        }
    }
}

public static childItem FindVisualChild<childItem>(DependencyObject obj) where childItem : DependencyObject
{
    // Search immediate children
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
    {
        DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);

        if (child is childItem)
            return (childItem)child;

        else
        {
            childItem childOfChild = FindVisualChild<childItem>(child);

            if (childOfChild != null)
                return childOfChild;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Don't manipulate UI elements in procedural code in WPF. That's what XAML is for. Use DataBinding.

Comment: `separated them via a change in tag name or something` - Wrong. You don't need horrible winforms-like crappy hacks in WPF. Use DataBinding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `FindVisualChild` method only returns the first `ListBox` found, if you want to find all `ListBoxes` that are in the `DataGrid` you will need to modify the method to return `IEnumerable<childItem>`

```
public static IEnumerable<childItem> FindVisualChildren<childItem>(DependencyObject obj) where childItem : DependencyObject
{
    // Search immediate children
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
    {
        DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);

        if (child is childItem)
          yield return (childItem)child;

        else
        {
            var childOfChild = FindVisualChildren<childItem>(child);

            if (childOfChild != null)
            {
                foreach(var item in childOfChild )
                {
                   yield return item;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

**Note: However if you follow the MVVM pattern in WPF this will be a lot easier than iterating visual elements**

Comment: Thanks sa_ddam213... How do I change the button1_Click event code to suit as I get error?
Hmmmm... gotta get my head around MVVM.